# Color of page number in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, color, classicthesis

I am using the `classicthesis` for my thesis and I have two issues related to the aspect of the table of contents (TOC).

As you can see from the attached picture

1. The color of the page number (and of the dots) in the TOC changes. How is that possible considering that the two chapters share the same TOC and `hyperref` settings?

   I'd like also to stress that, for chapter 2, the page number is colored as if it were a link but it's not a link (i.e. I cannot click on it) as I am expecting since I set the option `linktocpage=false`. Why does the color change?
2. I'd like that the first item in the TOC (List of figures) is not indented and had no dots. Any idea how to do it?

Unfortunately I cannot provide any minimal code as I have no idea what the problem might be. As I guess it might be related to the `hyperref` package here the settings:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV, linktocpage=false, breaklinks=true, fpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines, plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O, urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webbrown}
```

Any help, suggestion or idea about what I am doing wrong would be really appreciated.

[image]

**Update**

Here a minimal example with the settings I used. The problem about of the indentation of the first item of TOC is still present but I do not manage to reproduce in this example the issue concerning the wrong color of the page number

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{classicthesis,lipsum}

\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV, linktocpage=false, 
breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,
urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webbrown,
}

\begin{document}


\refstepcounter{dummy}

\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 

\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents 
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}

\clearpage

\begingroup 
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   List of Figures
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\acresetall
\refstepcounter{dummy} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename} 
\pdfbookmark[1]{\listfigurename}{lof} 
\listoffigures

\vspace{8ex}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   List of Tables
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename} 
\pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables

\sloppy % Just for this example

\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[31-40]

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[31-40]

\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[31-40]

\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[31-40]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What settings have you provided to `classicthesis`? [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/uufDJNNV) is a minimal example that you can use and add to so we can be on the same page.

Comment: Thanks! I used the minimal example you gave me. Which settings of `classicthesis` do you means? I have a long page of settings that I used for it (I got the settings so I did not write it myself most of it)

Comment: For reference, you should really compile what you present. After `\begin{document}` you write `\refstepcounter{dummy}` without ever defining the `dummy` counter. What does `dummy` do? Also, what does `\acresetall` do? Remember, in order to help you, provide us with sufficient means to replicate your current behaviour. That is, help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of Figures is indented in TOC because you have used `section` for the TOC entry, but you want `chapter`. Note that manual TOC entries for the lists are not recommended. I would suggest to use package `tocbibind` with option `nottoc`.

I did not get the dotted lines in TOC. When I add option `dottedtoc` for package `classicthesis` I can not reproduce your issue.

Package `classicthesis` loads package `hyperref`. So the later `\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}` is ignored (and it is not needed).

Additionally the switch between `\manualmark` and `\automark` inside the document can be replaced by settings in the preamble.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[dottedtoc]{classicthesis}

\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1
\hypersetup{
  %colorlinks=true,% already set by classicthesis
  pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV, linktocpage=false, 
  %breaklinks=true,% already set by classicthesis
  pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
  plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,
  hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,
  urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webbrown,
}

\ohead{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace#1}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 

\begin{document}

%\refstepcounter{dummy}% <- undefined counter

\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents} 
\tableofcontents 
\clearpage

\begingroup 
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   List of Figures
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\acresetall% <- undefined
%\refstepcounter{dummy} % <- undefined counter
\listoffigures

\vspace{8ex}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   List of Tables
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\refstepcounter{dummy}% <- undefined counter
\listoftables
\endgroup % <- added: should it be there?

%\sloppy % Just for this example

\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[31-40]

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[31-40]

\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[31-40]

\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[31-40]

\end{document}
```

[image]